# Unity C# Social.LoadUsers causes consistent crash when building to iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I get a list of Game Center user IDs using LoadScores, but unfortunately these only contain user IDs ("G:" followed by a string of digits). Now, previously we have used Social.LoadUsers on a string array of these IDs to retrieve user names, but I am seeing a consistent crash every time I do anything to access LoadUsers, e.g.:

```
List<string> userIDs = new List<string>();
foreach ((string, int) leader in allTimeTreasureLeaders)
{
    userIDs.Add(leader.Item1);
}

string[] userIDArray = userIDs.ToArray();

Social.LoadUsers(userIDArray, users =>
{
    foreach (IUserProfile user in users)
    {
        Debug.Log(user.userName);
    }
});
```

What is strange is I can see the print out of the names here, but then I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS anyway. Note that I'm not doing anything with these user names as the moment--it seems to just be the call to LoadUsers that causes the crash.

A couple of other comments to elaborate: this is in a static class, and allTimeTreasureLeaders is a List<(string, int)> that is populated in this class separately by a call to LoadScores. At the moment it contains 3 entries (our team).

Does anyone see an issue with what I'm doing or had this issue before?

EDIT: here is the stack trace.

[image: Stack Trace]

Comment: We're having the same problem on Unity 2020.1.4f1

Comment: Sorry to hear that Oneiros. We are on 2019.4.4. I'm very concerned this spells the end of using Game Center for us.

Comment: Does this crash happen on iOS 14 ? It might be an API change due to user privacy. Also update to the newest Unity LTS version, maybe it’s already fixed.

Comment: I see the crash on iOS 13, so I don't believe it's a privacy issue. Agreed on updating--while this has never fixed any issues for me in the past, it is worth a try.

Comment: Confirmed that updating to 2019.4.10 does not resolve issue.

Comment: I’m wondering if the changes to Xcode and loading a recurring leaderboard has something to do with messing up Unity’s Social API wrapper around GKLeaderboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Unity's wrapper is currently broken based on a thread on Unity's message boards where someone tracked a crash on scene changing to the same call to LoadUsers.

He, and we, resolved this issue by using Prime31's Game Center plugin. While I do not like spending $64 for one line of code, it was not worth my time to wait for Unity on this one. Unfortunately, native Unity Game Center for custom UI--assuming you want to display user names--is for all intents and purposes broken as far as I can tell.